# Question about 'recursively' creating threads in java - will a thread be garbage collected after spawning a new thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

Is this an acceptable way to produce a number of threads in series?

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static void execute(Job job) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable()) {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    SomeOtherClass.method(job)
                } finally {
                    boolean moreToDo = Database.check();
                    if (moreToDo) {
                        Job nextJob = Database.fetchNextJob();
                        SomeClass.execute(nextJob);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        t1.start();
    }
}
```

I am trying to run a series of jobs separate from the main thread of the application. I would like these jobs to run in series (one after the other) and not in parallel, due to constraints outside of my control. I should make it clear that these jobs are user generated, across multiple instances and sessions, and the jobs' information is stored in a database.

As I understand it, this will produce threads as follows:

```
M
|
|
|___1
|   |  
|   |
|   |
|   |___2
|   |   |
|   X   |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|       X
|
|
V
```

1. Thread `M` (`main` thread) will spawn thread `1` (`thread1`), and `thread1` will detach from `main`, losing all association.
2. `thread1` will then execute its code (`SomeOtherClass.method(job)`). It will eventually call its `finally`, and check the database for `moreToDo`.
3. If it finds that there is more to do, it will fetch some information and then call `SomeClass.execute()` with it (which it would have access to as everything is public).
4. This will lead to the spawning of `thread2` (`2`). `thread2` will then execute its code, `SomeOtherClass.method(job)`.
5. After `thread2` is spawned and detaches from `thread1`, `thread1` will have finished executing and will be left out for garbage collection.
6. Eventually `thread2` will call the code in the `finally` statement. Should it discover that `moreToDo == false` its execution will be finished and it will be left out for garbage collection.

I would like to avoid calling back to the main thread with an interface or somesuch to launch each job.

Is this how the threads would be handled (regardless of the merits of the implementation, I may have something better)?

Comment: Why not just use an `ExecutorService` and submit tasks to it? This seems like you're overcomplicating things.

Comment: I'd like to completely move the management of all Jobs into a non-main thread. An `ExecutorService` implementation looks like it would need to be managed by the main thread (or a thread dedicated to it, even more complicated), no?

Comment: What does that mean, "managed by the main thread?" If your program has an `ExecutorService`, then any thread that produces a task can submit the task, and the ExecutorService eventually will perform it.

Comment: If you want to "run them in series" then why do you need more than one thread?

Comment: @user1676075 You're correct, and I've realized a better implementation as I was writing the question. I still was curious and decided to post more for academic reasons.

Comment: @Solomon Slow, Thanks, I see what you mean. I'll go read some docs

Comment: @SolomonSlow I don't think an ExecutorService fits this implementation. As I understand it I would use a single thread, and fill its queue with runnables. I would like to avoid this, storing my jobs in the database and checking for them on completion, instead of storing them in memory in the queue.

Comment: @jsarbour, one way to prevent the queue from growing would be to have each task submit exactly one additional task as its last act. That would be very similar to your original proposal, except it would be more efficient because it would not create and destroy a new thread for every task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "yes" - when the Thread exits its `run()` method, it terminates and is GC'd, even if it spawned another thread.

But your worker task should not be both doing work *and* checking for work to do. Instead, use a producer/consumer pattern, the concept of which is:

- create a size-limited `BlockingQueue`
- use a `while (Database.check())` loop to put work items into the queue
- use size-limited `ExecutorService` to take items from the queue and process them
- the use of size limits and blocking calls creates back pressure on the producer and caps resources used by the consumers

Comment: Just because a thread terminates, that does not necessarily mean that the `Thread` instance that controlled it has become eligible for garbage collection or, that the space allocated for its call stack will be reclaimed.  The OP is asking for proof that those things all will be reclaimed. My _guess_ would be, probably yes, but I could not say for sure without doing some research. But then, I'd never have any reason to _do_ that research because I'd be using an `ExecutorService` instead.

Comment: Good answer but I think it doesn't differentiate between a thread and a Thread. The GC only reclaims Threads (instances of the java.lang.Thread class) and not threads, which are things known to the operating system and the OS clears the resources used by it.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException in the context of this question, we're only talking about java Threads.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions on the design pattern. I think I want to keep the queued jobs in the database, as it can grow during execution of any given job. The only time I know to check the queue for more is on thread completion. I believe this would invalidate that pattern, no?

Comment: @jsarbour no - this pattern will work with delays anywhere in the system. If you want to wait until jobs become available, you can use something like (pseudocode): `while(true) { if (Database.check()) addToQueue; sleep 1 minute; if (someVolatileFlag) break;}`

Comment: @Bohemian would that block the main thread for the time that it is sleeping?

Comment: @jsarbour no, because you run the while loop in its own thread. Everything runs in the background.

Comment: But then I would carry around the whole queue (which is expected to be rather sizable) both in memory and in the database, and be performing time-based polling on the database (which I'd like to avoid). It seems to me that the thread ending, as an event, could be harnessed somehow to produce a much more neat solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197951/discussion-between-jsarbour-and-bohemian).